# Locks on a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wamp, mutex

I have a MySQL database which I need to lock out entirely when I do certain operations. ACID is not sufficient for me. The database is accessed through a web server which acts as a service, assigning numbers that are both sequential and unique. No, it's not a simple incrementing integer; it has complicated rules based on a query string and previously assigned numbers stored in the database, but it is monotonically increasing. I have implemented a stored SQL function which assigns these numbers with the proper algorithm. But, say my Apache server (with PHP) were to request two numbers at about the same time, I think I could get the same number twice. That's no good. That's Failure with a capital F for my application. It isn't performance critical, so mutexing the whole number assignment function is a valid solution. What's the best way to achieve this, and what are the pitfalls?

Comment: See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) for a few options.

Comment: Not so sure I got the question right, but what is the problem with a dummy table (innodb) and read-lock on that table?

Comment: I like LOCK TABLES, shmosel, but Dekel, why do you say read lock? Isn't write lock what I want?